# How do I save multiple strings?

Tags: string, cocoa, swift, nsuserdefaults, savestate

I have this code in an ibaction

```
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue1.text, forKey: TAValue1Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue2.text, forKey: TAValue2Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue3.text, forKey: TAValue3Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue4.text, forKey: TAValue4Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue5.text, forKey: TAValue5Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue6.text, forKey: TAValue6Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue7.text, forKey: TAValue7Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue8.text, forKey: TAValue8Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue9.text, forKey: TAValue9Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany1.text, forKey: TAHowMany1Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany2.text, forKey: TAHowMany2Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany3.text, forKey: TAHowMany3Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany4.text, forKey: TAHowMany4Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany5.text, forKey: TAHowMany5Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany6.text, forKey: TAHowMany6Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany7.text, forKey: TAHowMany7Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany8.text, forKey: TAHowMany8Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany9.text, forKey: TAHowMany9Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal1.text, forKey: TATotal1Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal2.text, forKey: TATotal2Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal3.text, forKey: TATotal3Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal4.text, forKey: TATotal4Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal5.text, forKey: TATotal5Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal6.text, forKey: TATotal6Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal7.text, forKey: TATotal7Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal8.text, forKey: TATotal8Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal9.text, forKey: TATotal9Key)
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal10.text, forKey: TATotal10Key)
```

I feel that Xcode is taking the last text (TATotal10.text) and saving only that. This is then loaded in every text field box I want data reloaded into.
How do I create individually saved strings?
Cheers

here is my load data code.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

    TAValue1.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue1Key)
    TAValue2.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue2Key)
    TAValue3.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue3Key)
    TAValue4.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue4Key)
    TAValue5.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue5Key)
    TAValue6.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue6Key)
    TAValue7.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue7Key)
    TAValue8.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue8Key)
    TAValue9.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAValue9Key)
    TAHowMany1.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany1Key)
    TAHowMany2.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany2Key)
    TAHowMany3.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany3Key)
    TAHowMany4.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany4Key)
    TAHowMany5.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany5Key)
    TAHowMany6.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany6Key)
    TAHowMany7.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany7Key)
    TAHowMany8.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany8Key)
    TAHowMany9.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TAHowMany9Key)
    TATotal1.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal1Key)
    TATotal2.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal2Key)
    TATotal3.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal3Key)
    TATotal4.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal4Key)
    TATotal5.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal5Key)
    TATotal6.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal6Key)
    TATotal7.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal7Key)
    TATotal8.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal8Key)
    TATotal9.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal9Key)
    TATotal10.text = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey(TATotal10Key)

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it is loaded into every text field. This code doesn't load anything in to text fields, it takes the values out f the text fields. Do you have more code that pulls the values out again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your key constants are all the same literal string. (ie, you copy/pasted `TATotalxxxKey` and renumbered them but didn't change the `@"literalstringxxx"` definition for each)

Comment: You were correct. Thank you so much I will post my new code shortly

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create arrays of labels or textfields and do something like this:

```
for var i = 1; i <= TAValues.count; i++
{
    NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValues[i-1], forKey: "TAValue\(i)Key")
}
for var i = 0; i < TAHowManys.count; i++
{
    NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValues[i], forKey: "TAValue\(i+1)Key")
}
```

Comment: -1 because using constants instead of string literals is the better approach since they can't be mistyped once defined and this answer doesn't really address the issue of why all the strings appear to be the same once retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the response from Joshua Nozzi I was able to alter my code to this and it has resolved the issue .

```
var TAValue1Key = String(01)
var TAValue2Key = String(02)
var TAValue3Key = String(03)
var TAValue4Key = String(04)
var TAValue5Key = String(05)
var TAValue6Key = String(06)
var TAValue7Key = String(07)
var TAValue8Key = String(08)
var TAValue9Key = String(09)
var TAHowMany1Key = String(10)
var TAHowMany2Key = String(11)
var TAHowMany3Key = String(12)
var TAHowMany4Key = String(13)
var TAHowMany5Key = String(14)
var TAHowMany6Key = String(15)
var TAHowMany7Key = String(16)
var TAHowMany8Key = String(17)
var TAHowMany9Key = String(18)
var TATotal1Key = String(19)
var TATotal2Key = String(20)
var TATotal3Key = String(21)
var TATotal4Key = String(22)
var TATotal5Key = String(23)
var TATotal6Key = String(24)
var TATotal7Key = String(25)
var TATotal8Key = String(26)
var TATotal9Key = String(27)
var TATotal10Key = String(28)
```

Previously I had no number within each string().

I also changed my save code to

```
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue1.text, forKey: String(01))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue2.text, forKey: String(02))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue3.text, forKey: String(03))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue4.text, forKey: String(04))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue5.text, forKey: String(05))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue6.text, forKey: String(06))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue7.text, forKey: String(07))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue8.text, forKey: String(08))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAValue9.text, forKey: String(09))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany1.text, forKey: String(10))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany2.text, forKey: String(11))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany3.text, forKey: String(12))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany4.text, forKey: String(13))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany5.text, forKey: String(14))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany6.text, forKey: String(15))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany7.text, forKey: String(16))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany8.text, forKey: String(17))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TAHowMany9.text, forKey: String(18))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal1.text, forKey: String(19))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal2.text, forKey: String(20))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal3.text, forKey: String(21))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal4.text, forKey: String(22))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal5.text, forKey: String(23))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal6.text, forKey: String(24))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal7.text, forKey: String(25))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal8.text, forKey: String(26))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal9.text, forKey: String(27))
NSUserDefaults().setObject(TATotal10.text, forKey: String(28))
```

because my load code was defined by the string name and the string name now has a string number allocated there was no need to to change my load code.
For all load code based in other view controllers .swift files I simply name the string what ever i want and allocate it with the string number from the first .swift. E.G I use the string TATotal10Key in another view controller.

I named it

```
var TaxableTotalText = String(28)
```

it can be called what ever I like as long as it has the correct number associated to it.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score -1):

To store data in NSUSerDefaults, try this

```
// Saving data in nsuserdefaults
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:TAValue1.text forKey:TAValue1Key];
[defaults setObject:TAValue2.text forKey:TAValue2Key];
[defaults setObject:TAValue3.text forKey:TAValue3Key];
[defaults setObject:TAValue4.text forKey:TAValue4Key];
[defaults setObject:TAValue5.text forKey:TAValue5Key];


// Fetching data from nsuserdefaults corresponding to key
NSString* taValue1 = [defaults objectForKey:TAValue1Key];
NSString* taValue2 = [defaults objectForKey:TAValue2Key];
NSString* taValue3 = [defaults objectForKey:TAValue3Key];
NSString* taValue4 = [defaults objectForKey:TAValue4Key];
NSString* taValue5 = [defaults objectForKey:TAValue5Key];
```

Try this. Hopefully it will help you.. Thanks